# Combining Records based for consecutive records without loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table for storing contract start date and end date of employees.

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee_Contract_Dates (RecordID INT IDENTITY(1,1), EmpID INT, 
                              Contract_Start_Date DATE, Contract_End_Date DATE)
INSERT INTO #Employee_Contract_Dates(EmpID, Contract_Start_Date, Contract_End_Date)
SELECT 1 AS EmpID, '2020-01-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, '2020-12-31' AS Contract_End_Date UNION
SELECT 100 AS EmpID, '2015-05-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, '2015-10-31' AS Contract_End_Date 

INSERT INTO #Employee_Contract_Dates(EmpID, Contract_Start_Date, Contract_End_Date)
SELECT 1 AS EmpID, '2021-01-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, '2021-06-30' AS Contract_End_Date UNION
SELECT 1 AS EmpID, '2021-07-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, '2021-09-30' AS Contract_End_Date UNION
SELECT 1 AS EmpID, '2022-01-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, '2022-12-31' AS Contract_End_Date UNION
SELECT 1 AS EmpID, '2023-01-01' AS Contract_Start_Date, NULL AS Contract_End_Date


SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date, RecordID ) AS RowNum
INTO #ContractSource
FROM #Employee_Contract_Dates
```

[image]

I need to combined records with consecutive dates into one record (show the **continuous duration** an employee had contract **in one row**)

Following will do the combining process for first and second row

```
SELECT A.RecordID, A.EmpID, A.Contract_Start_Date,
        ISNULL(B.Contract_End_Date, A.Contract_End_Date),
        B.RecordID AS Unwanted_ID
FROM #ContractSource A
INNER JOIN #ContractSource B
    ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID 
    AND A.RowNum = 1
    AND B.RowNum = 2
    AND  B.Contract_Start_Date = DATEADD(DAY , 1, A.Contract_End_Date )  ---Consecutive days records
WHERE 1 = 1
```

[image]

How to do it recursively without a WHILE loop?

Expected Output

[image]

Post Note References:

[SQL Classic Problem: Identifying Gaps and Islands Across Overlapping Date Ranges](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sql-classic-problem-identifying-gaps-and-islands-across-overlapping-date-ranges-5681b5fcdb8#:%7E:text=Gaps%20and%20islands%20is%20a,sequence%20is%20missing%20(gaps).)

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the classic gaps solution:

```sql
SELECT
    EmpId,
    MIN(Contract_start_date) AS startDate,
    MAX(Contract_end_date) AS endDate,
    MIN(RecordID) AS RecordID
FROM    (
    SELECT
      *,
      period_number = SUM(is_new_period_starts) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Contract_start_date)
    FROM    (
        SELECT
          is_new_period_starts = CASE WHEN datediff(day, LAG(Contract_End_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY empID ORDER BY Contract_start_date), Contract_Start_Date) <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
          *
        FROM    #Employee_Contract_Dates e
        ) x
    ) x
GROUP BY EmpID, period_number
```

It calculates each time previous enddate isn't one day behind current startdate and increases the "counter" which creates new grouping.
Finally, you select the minimum and maximum dates per group to get the consecutive dates

Answer (score 3):

For `RecordID` I assume you want the one corresponding to the `Contract_Start_Date`.

An approach which just uses window functions on a stream ordered by `EmpId,Contract_Start_Date` and no final `GROUP BY` step ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ys8LPxvC)).

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       --We are only retaining the rows where a group ends. In the retained rows this value will be the "Contract_Start_Date of the next group"
       NextContract_Start_Date = LEAD(Contract_Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date),
       --We are only retaining the rows where a group ends. In the retained rows this value will be the "RecordID of the next group"
       NextRecordID = LEAD(RecordID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date),
       --For the very first group there is no previous group so we need the next two values available for that case
       FirstRecordID = FIRST_VALUE(RecordID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),    
       FirstContract_Start_Date  = FIRST_VALUE(Contract_Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM #Employee_Contract_Dates
)
SELECT RecordID = LAG(NextRecordID, 1, FirstRecordID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date), 
       EmpID,
       --Getting the "Contract_Start_Date of the next group" for the previous group gives us the "Contract_Start_Date of this group".
       --Fallback to FirstContract_Start_Date if there is no previous group
       Contract_Start_Date = LAG(NextContract_Start_Date, 1, FirstContract_Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date),
       Contract_End_Date
FROM T
WHERE NextContract_Start_Date IS NULL  /*Last Group*/ OR NextContract_Start_Date > DATEADD(DAY, 1, Contract_End_Date) /* or break in groups*/;
```